# Prompt user for Username Password in browser while using winsock

Tags: c++, stream, winsock

I have written code in C++ with Winsock. It converts a video to mjpeg stream and sends it over TCP using Winsock in windows. Now I am able to see the video in any browser with the link.
But the problem is that anyone with the link can see it. I want to prompt the user to enter username and password to access the feed, whenever he types the IP address.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <winsock.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #define PORT        unsigned long
    #define ADDRPOINTER   int*
    struct _INIT_W32DATA
    {
       WSADATA w;
       _INIT_W32DATA() { WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 1 ), &w ); }
    } _init_once;


#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
using namespace std;


class MJPGWriter
{
    SOCKET sock;
    fd_set master;
    int timeout; // master sock timeout, shutdown after timeout millis.
    int quality; // jpeg compression [1..100]

    int _write( int sock, char *s, int len ) 
    { 
        if ( len < 1 ) { len = strlen(s); }
        return ::send( sock, s, len, 0 );
    }

public:

    MJPGWriter(int port = 0) 
        : sock(INVALID_SOCKET) 
        , timeout(20000)
        , quality(30)
    {
        FD_ZERO( &master );
            if (port)
                open(port);
    }

    ~MJPGWriter() 
    {
        release();
    }

    bool release()
    {
        if ( sock != INVALID_SOCKET )
            ::shutdown( sock, 2 );
        sock = (INVALID_SOCKET);
        return false;
    }

    bool open( int port )
    {
        sock = ::socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) ;

        SOCKADDR_IN address;       
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        address.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        address.sin_port        = ::htons(port);
        if ( ::bind( sock, (SOCKADDR*) &address, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            cerr << "error : couldn't bind sock "<<sock<<" to port "<<port<<"!" << endl;
            return release();
        }
        if ( ::listen( sock, 10 ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            cerr << "error : couldn't listen on sock "<<sock<<" on port "<<port<<" !" << endl;
            return release();
        }
        FD_SET( sock, &master );    
        return true;
    }

    bool isOpened() 
    {
        return sock != INVALID_SOCKET; 
    }

    bool write(const cv::Mat & frame)
    {
        fd_set rread = master;
        struct timeval to = {0,timeout};
        SOCKET maxfd = sock+1;

        if ( ::select( maxfd, &rread, NULL, NULL, &to ) <= 0 )
            return true; // nothing broken, there's just noone listening

        std::vector<uchar>outbuf;
        std::vector<int> params;
        params.push_back(cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
        params.push_back(quality);
        cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, outbuf, params);
        int outlen = outbuf.size();

        #ifdef _WIN32 
        for ( unsigned i=0; i<rread.fd_count; i++ )
        {
            SOCKET s = rread.fd_array[i];    // fd_set on win is an array, while ...
        #else         
        for ( int s=0; s<maxfd; s++ )
        {
            if ( ! FD_ISSET(s,&rread) )      // ... on linux it's a bitmask ;)
                continue;
        #endif                   
            if ( s == sock ) // request on master socket, accept and send main header.
            {
                int         addrlen = sizeof(SOCKADDR);
                SOCKADDR_IN address = {0};     
                SOCKET      client  = ::accept( sock,  (SOCKADDR*)&address, &addrlen );
                if ( client == SOCKET_ERROR )
                {
                    cerr << "error : couldn't accept connection on sock " << sock<< " !" << endl;
                    return false;
                }
                maxfd=(maxfd>client?maxfd:client);
                FD_SET( client, &master );
                _write( client,"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n",0);
                _write( client,
                    "Server: Mozarella/2.2\r\n"
                    "Accept-Range: bytes\r\n"
                    "Connection: close\r\n"
                    "Max-Age: 0\r\n"
                    "Expires: 0\r\n"
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n"
                    "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
                    "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=mjpegstream\r\n"
                    "\r\n",0);
                cerr << "new client " << client << endl;
            } 
            else // existing client, just stream pix
            {
                char head[400];
                sprintf(head,"--mjpegstream\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %lu\r\n\r\n",outlen);
                _write(s,head,0);
                int n = _write(s,(char*)(&outbuf[0]),outlen);
                //cerr << "known client " << s << " " << n << endl;
                if ( n < outlen )
                {
                    cerr << "kill client " << s << endl;
                    ::shutdown(s,2);
                    FD_CLR(s,&master);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

I am using it by sending image frame and port number to writer.

Comment: It's not easy with plain C++. You need to return a 403 error and then handle digest authentication. Here is a PHP method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Can I do it in my existing code? I am working on visual studio 2010. So after PHP authentication, it will just run my existing code?

Comment: You have to implement all that PHP code in c++. You have to constantly check the headers for the presence of the credentials, for each request. As I said, it's not easy and too broad to discuss here.

Comment: Ohh! Is there any library for it which I can use with my code?

Comment: Probably not as server side development is usually done in PHP which runs on top of an existing server like Apache or nginx which will handle all the dirty work for you. While creating a http server in C++ is possible, no one would bother today.

Comment: OKay. I'll look into it. Can you help me with something else? Can I create an HTTP server and use this code? For example with IIS?